# google map nearby place search not showing some results when radius changes

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm trying to integrate the google map place search api for finding nearby masjid.
Everything is working perfectly. The problem is that, if I increase the radius parameter, some results are missing with the previous one.

For Example:
This will list all the results within 1000 meter.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=11.1689003,75.8214371&radius=1000&keyword=masjid&key=[API_KEY]

If I'm changing the radius to 5000 meter, some results are not listing.

one of the missing json result is:

```
{
"geometry":{
    "location":{
        "lat":11.1615313,
        "lng":75.823492
    },
    "viewport":{
        "northeast":{
            "lat":11.1628802802915,
            "lng":75.82484098029151
        },
        "southwest":{
            "lat":11.1601823197085,
            "lng":75.82214301970851
        }
    }
},
"icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/worship_islam-71.png",
"id":"f556b20398feffe38b024b377bbb0edf872d5a6b",
"name":"Palakkal Masjid Karuvan Thiruthy",
"place_id":"ChIJcTPuurhQpjsR-kwaw-HG8ls",
"reference":"CmRRAAAAjqQfOZA-J003xYiT07aK2fEiens0Stkss2JDVGaKb6kjfMVRVYXg_muLS1l6R2jsFZTN-zsG17wfnSX1ViRie_GgPn0G0oLpIDl2gcrDRXmQ9I-VlUwQ1w7Cth4i5IRQEhBmKNgiAzVFtT0pPf7Q6SgWGhRUjSgdih5wLI4VynVgv0GdjNikqw",
"scope":"GOOGLE",
"types":[
    "mosque",
    "place_of_worship",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
],
"vicinity":"Karuvanthiruthy"
```

},

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing you should understand is that Places API nearby search is not working as a database search and doesn't return all possible results.

As you can see in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchPaging) the Places API nearby search can return up to 60 results (3 pages with 20 items in each one). In your example the items will be ordered by prominence. When you increase the radius to 5000 meters the new items with higher prominence can appear in the results and they can exclude the less prominent item 'Palakkal Masjid Karuvan Thiruthy' from the 60 returned by the Places API web service.

How Google calculates the prominence is out of my scope, so I cannot say why one item is more prominent than another one.

Comment: Thanks @xomena for your reply. 
Is there anyway to combine all the result (from different pages) in single json?